# How to check XML Binding generated Delphi files for null without breaking encapsulation

Tags: xml, delphi, data-binding

In my opinion calling `XML.attrisnull('something')` or manually checking the XML for the existence of a child element when I would prefer to just say `if XML.something = null then DontUseIt();` breaks violates some principle, it leaves ugly strings in the code and is pretty much pointless because all I'm trying to do is check for the non-existence of data.

So, my question is, is there a function I'm missing that can maybe temporarily suspend creating new object when I try to check `XML.Element = null`?

[The tutorial](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34110) says this is a feature:

> You will notice that there's no function whatsoever to create a child node unless it is a composite node.

but it's really a pain in the neck because I have to pass in booleans for whether or not a thing exists before using it.

Comment: Some people, when presented with a problem, think “I know, I’ll use XML.”  `<Problem:Worsening>
  <Problem:TimeDescription>Now</Problem:TimeDescription>
  <Problem:Posessive>they have</Problem:Posessive>
  <Problem:Quantity>many, many</Problem:Quantity>
  <Problem:WorseningDescription>more problems</Problem:WorseningDescription>
</ProblemWorsening>`

Comment: Well, I like the bindings, I'm doing JAXB on in Eclipse and sending the data over via SOAP as strings (not complex structures) then binding them to XML interfaces and it's all real zippy, except this, which is dumb.